# How to loop a data to get header, detail and total invoice

Tags: c#

I have a data (in .txt)

```
ABC@ID@550656019@IDR@2667378@asdasd@gmail.com
INV@======================================================================
INV@REFERENCE                                           AMOUNT
INV@956VII2019                                           2,667,378   
INV@TOTAL INVOICE                                       2,667,378    
DEF@ID@550656019@IDR@100186049|efghij@gmail.com
INV@======================================================================
INV@REFERENCE                                           AMOUNT
INV@A019128B                                             2,726,903   
INV@A019206                                              3,119,665   
INV@A019126                                              6,296,663   
INV@A019138                                              6,405,257   
INV@A019036                                              6,700,000   
INV@19149                                                7,101,957   
INV@A019128A                                             9,171,400   
INV@A019164                                              9,814,861   
INV@A019168                                             12,638,424   
INV@19109                                               12,675,303   
INV@A018928                                             23,535,617   
INV@TOTAL INVOICE                                       100,186,049    
ABC@ID@550656019@IDR@97160972@bcdbcd@gmail.com
INV@======================================================================
INV@REFERENCE                                           AMOUNT
INV@190700185                                            2,786,589   
INV@190700184                                           10,191,000   
INV@190700164                                           11,844,283   
INV@190700218                                           11,930,350   
INV@190700165                                           19,017,750   
INV@190700163                                           41,391,000   
INV@TOTAL INVOICE                                       97,160,972
```

How to process the data so I can get the output like :

```
0|ABC|550656019|99828350|2
1|ABC|asdasd@gmail.com
2|956VII2019|2667378
1|ABC|bcdbcd@gmail.com
2|190700185|2,786,589   
2|190700184|10,191,000   
2|190700164|11,844,283   
2|190700218|11,930,350   
2|190700165|19,017,750   
2|190700163|41,391,000  
0|DEF|550656019|100186049|1
1|DEF|efghij@gmail.com
2|A019128B|2,726,903   
2|A019206|3,119,665   
2|A019126|6,296,663   
2|A019138|6,405,257   
2|A019036|6,700,000   
2|19149|7,101,957   
2|A019128A|9,171,400   
2|A019164|9,814,861   
2|A019168|12,638,424   
2|19109|12,675,303   
2|A018928|23,535,617
```

Explanation :

```
0 is for header
it will check if the data (not the row with invoice) has the same field or not (field 1("ABC") - field 4("IDR")) if yes, it will total the amount of the total invoice , and count the total record who has the same field 
so the format will be "0|field1|field3|total invoice amount|total record"

1 is for detail
it will list the detail of the header -> you can check that each row has different email , the detail will be split between the email.

2 is for invoice detail
just list the Invoice (after references) and the amount, but not the total invoice 

after you put the detail for one email, it will list the invoice then it will start to list the detail with different emails
```

I'm already stuck here and already try to convert .txt to .xlsx (hope it will be easier) but it's not.

Code to convert to xlsx

```
 //string[] 
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);
            //read line then split
            xlApp = new excel.Application();
            xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
            xlWs = (excel.Worksheet)xlWb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            row = 1;
            col = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                textsplit = lines[i].Split('@');
                for (int j = 0; j < textsplit.Length; j++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        xlWs.Cells[row, col] = textsplit[j].ToString();
                        col++;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }

                row++;
                col = 1;
            }
            //save ke file excel tampungan
            xlWb.SaveAs(appPath + "testing.xlsx", excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, missing, missing,
                 false, false, excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
            xlWb.Close();
            closeExcel(xlApp); closeExcel(xlApp);

            textBox2.Text = appPath + "testing.xlsx";
            //ambil field penting dan dimasukkkan ke .txt
```

Only can generate the header, without total amount and total record because I don't know the best logic to loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowheader; i++)
            {
                totalrecord= 1;
                temp = 1;
                foreach (string datas in data)
                {
                    if (!fulldataheader[i][0].Equals("INV"))
                    {
                        if (data.Equals(fulldataheader[i][0] + " " + fulldataheader[i][1] + " " + fulldataheader[i][2] + " " + fulldataheader[i][3]))
                        {
                            totalrecord++;
                            //temp = 2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            data.Add(fulldataheader[i][0] + " " + fulldataheader[i][1] + " " + fulldataheader[i][2] + " " + fulldataheader[i][3]);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (string datas in data)
                {
                   {
                    if (fulldataheader[i][0].Equals("ABC"))
                    {
                        path = appPath + "LLG.txt";
                        header = "0|CR|SP/MP|" + rnd.Next(10000000, 99999999) + "|||" + 
                     fulldataheader[i][6] + "|" + fulldataheader[i][2] + "|123|123|totalamount|" + 
                     totalrecord + "|LLG|IDR|||";
                        temp = 1;
                    }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
if (temp == 1)
                    {
                        if (!File.Exists(path))
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                            {
                                sw.WriteLine(header);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (File.Exists(path))
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
                            {
                                sw.WriteLine(header);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

I would group all the data by customer + email into a SortedDictionary, then use LINQ expressions in the end to gather the result. Example implementation:

```
# Read data
var data = new SortedDictionary<(string id, string idr, string email), List<(string reference, decimal amount)>>();
using (var input = File.OpenText("input.txt"))
{
    List<(string reference, decimal amount)> currentInvoice = null;

    for (var line = input.ReadLine(); line != null; line = input.ReadLine())
    {
        var fields = line.Split(new char[] { '@' }, 6);
        switch (fields.Length)
        {
            case 2:
                // Sanitize input
                if (fields[0] != "INV")
                {
                    throw new Exception("Unknown record type.");
                }
                if (currentInvoice == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invoice without context.");
                }

                // Parse
                var invoiceEntry = fields[1].Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (invoiceEntry.Length == 2)
                {
                    decimal amount;
                    if (decimal.TryParse(invoiceEntry[1],
                        NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        out amount))
                    {
                        currentInvoice.Add((invoiceEntry[0], amount));
                    }
                }

                break;

            case 6:
                var currentContext = (id: fields[0], idr: fields[2], email: fields[5]);
                if (!data.TryGetValue(currentContext, out currentInvoice))
                {
                    currentInvoice = new List<(string reference, decimal amount)>();
                    data.Add(currentContext, currentInvoice);
                }
                break;

            default:
                throw new Exception("Unknown record.");
        }
    }
}

# Print data
foreach (var customerData in data.Keys.GroupBy(x => (x.id, x.idr), x => x.email))
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("|",
        "0",
        customerData.Key.id,
        customerData.Key.idr,
        data.Where(x => x.Key.id == customerData.Key.id && x.Key.idr == customerData.Key.idr).Sum(x => x.Value.Sum(d => d.amount)),
        customerData.Count()
        ));

    foreach (var email in customerData)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join("|",
            "1",
            customerData.Key.id,
            email
            ));

        foreach (var invoiceEntry in data[(customerData.Key.id, customerData.Key.idr, email)])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join("|",
                "2",
                invoiceEntry.reference,
                invoiceEntry.amount.ToString("n0")
                ));
        }
    }
}
```

I would also point out some inconsistencies in your data; if they are intentional, the algorithm may need to be adjusted accordingly:

- customer DEF has its email separated by | instead of @ (I assumed it's an example mistake),
- invoice entries use thousand separators, but totals at customer level do not (this is only affecting output, as totals are calculated from invoice entries, not taken from customer row),
- most important: totals do not add up; total for DEF customer is 100186050, not 100186049. You may want to pay more attention to this.

Comment: thankyou, i will try it first , and sorry for the details , i will fix it